# Transferred question = invisible rep?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, reputation, migration

So, I answered a question on SO that was somewhat popular; my answer got quite a few upvotes.  However, the question got deleted; now my recent activity -> reputation doesn't show anything for that, but new upvotes I'm getting are not awarding reputation (as I've apparently hit my 200 / day limit).  What's up with that?  Can we possibly get to see all the rep that was awarded to us in a day, regardless of whether or not the question was deleted?

Edit:  Okay, just found out what happened; it seems that the question was closed and automatically transferred over to ServerFault.  What makes this interesting, though, is that it got transferred to community wiki on ServerFault, and so I got no rep on SF for my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really; and you may find that the numbers change after a rep recalc (rep from things that get deleted may be lost, although you should still get any rep that you "missed" in the day from the rep cap).

Let me know if you want me to force a recalc.

Also - can you cite the question?

Comment: The question was the one about the guy freaking out about how his site got SQL injected.  For what it's worth, the recalc wouldn't really matter much, as I should have crossed my rep limit either way today, what with everything else going on.  I'm actually interested just in the fact that you can force a recalc, though; I didn't know that was possible for mods to do.

Comment: That question sounds awesome (though doesn't belong on SO). I'm upset I missed it. Was he blaming anybody in particular for it being injected, or was he just freaking out in general? Maybe we should have a wtf.stackoverflow.com where we can just move these questions for posterity.

Comment: Ah c**p; it turns out that actually you <s>are</s> were 97 too high (by the logs). I hate to be the bearer of bad news... but (cough). If it makes you feel any better, I lost 100 myself earlier in the week for the same reason... this can be, for example, due to deleted posts or (more rarely) unusual votes. Sorry.

Comment: (actually, even now you are maxed on rep, so the drop doesn't relate to anything today)

Comment: Well that was a spectacular backfire. Well done, asynchronous calculations. Well done.

Comment: Yes, it was rather. I feel bad, but rep recalcs aren't uncommon, so it probably just saves on a surprise a few days down the line...

Comment: Ah, no worries in particular; it's not that much rep.  If I actually got my association bonus (hint, hint) I might actually be up from where I was before...

Comment: Man, that's weird, though; the recent activity -> rep page is still showing very odd results and numbers with rep.  It still seems to count the rep from the deleted post, but the ordering is weird now too...

Comment: @Eric:  Oh yeah, it was an amusing post.  The guy wasn't blaming anyone; he was looking for advice as to what to do now that his site had been compromised.  Tragic, but amusing.  :-)

Comment: "hint, hint" - is there a problem with the association bonus? It usually works fine? Note that I don't have any power over that one...

Comment: All development must being done with a `where userid = 28053` clause on it just to mess with you.

Comment: @MarcGravell:  yes, my association bonus has never arrived, for any of my accounts.  SO never gave it to me (AFAICT), and it's certainly not arrived for either my meta or SF accounts.  I've raised the point a couple of times, and each time, I got the impression that the mods didn't want to be bothered, so I figured I'd just wait it out...

Comment: Just to be clear - the *community moderators* have no influence on the cross-site bonus; it is really more an issue for the devevelopment team.

Comment: @MarcGravell: aha, thx for the info.