# I just lost 286 rep points. Why?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

So, I login today and notice that I have gone from 11,481 down to 11,195.  I don;t see how this could have happened through the voting system.  I know that another member was annoyed when I corrected their response in a comment and proceeded to arbitrarily downvote many of my responses, but that could not account for 286 points.  It's not the end of the world here, but it is a little discouraging.

Comment: probably a recalc

Comment: Also keep in mind that the '286 was a venerable processor, and quite nimble it its time.  You should feel privileged to now share some connection with that choice silicon.

Comment: @Pollyanna: LOL

Comment: Maybe a good time to bring this up again: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35566/make-scheduled-reputation-recalcs-to-increase-transparency

Comment: Here, have some sympathy upvotes.

Comment: I like how everyone remembers the exact reputation they had the previous day. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Given that your [reputation graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) doesn't show a sudden drop, then chances are that a reputation recalc was done on your account.

This may have been triggered by the abusive downvoting you experienced.  When those downvotes are deleted, a rep recalc is done to reflect the deleted votes.

In most cases a rep recalc results in a lower rep due to migrated and deleted posts.

Comment: Hmmm, so abusive downvoting being fixed causes me to lose rep?  Seems pretty backwards, but ok.  Thanks.

Comment: @Ed - A lot of users have slightly inflated reputation because they just haven't had a recalc. There are apocryphal tales that someday, the skies will open and a site-wide rep recalc will occur, but people who believe in such mysticism are far too simple for sophisticated folk such as you and I.

Comment: I'm too old for fairy tales.