# About voting and reputation

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-recalc

I was playing around trying to see what triggers rep changes <sup><sup>gosub 1</sup></sup>. I know that there is a /reputation page, and Nick has reiterated many times that triggering a recalc is ***expensive*** (always emphasized).

I used to get rep differences between current and /reputation in the tens, which in my first 60 days at Stack Overflow happens often.  I never let it go too far, since I recalc often.  But since the last week or two, or since the latest global recalc that spawned the grammatically dubious floating top banner, it seems to have stabilised and at times I *suspect* auto-corrects itself.

**Q1:** Has any changes been made to make reputation track closer to the true rep (if we take result of recalc to be "true")?
**Q2:** Are there more points where mini-recalcs or adjustments occur?
**Q3:** If rep reversal is immediate in the test case to follow, why doesn't either the increase or decrease update the summary total? i.e the header had `70 v Today`, the list had 200 + 0 rep votes (post rep-cap)

---

<sup><sup>1:</sup></sup> Okay what I did was to go to waffles' (Sam's) profile, and open up 17* (or so) answers that I have not voted on.  Noting that Sam has 70 rep today, I upvoted all 17* and watched the rep reach the daily limit.  Then I removed the upvotes *half*-expecting the rep to stay (they got removed).<sub><sub>return</sub></sub>

Comment: Can you please make that a `gosub`, because I can't read your question. :(

Comment: If you remove a vote the reputation change caused by that vote is undone immediately. It's always worked like this - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40519/show-rep-lost-or-gained-from-rescinded-votes (and a couple of others).

Comment: @Bobby You're testing my age.. that goes way back. I had to check for the right syntax :)

Comment: Thank you. :) Also, maybe there was a change in your behavior? Missing reputation is a sign that you've been answering on questions which either got deleted or migrated. Maybe you stopped doing that without noticing?

Comment: I posted a screenshot to my question about recalc frequency.  You'll remember, the one where you made merciless fun of rep obsession.  It isn't exactly rosy.

Answer (score 3):

The things that cause rep to go out of sync with reality are deletions, migrations, and a few other odd ducks, *such as abuse detection.*

Most user initiated actions, such as voting or unvoting have always result in correct reputation scores.

You can test some of these problems by deleting your own answers and questions.

Unlike deletions and migrations, as you found out, abuse detection results in an automatic recalculation.  However, that recalculation only needs to be performed on one or two users (the abuser and the victim).

Some migrated or deleted questions would result in dozens of users needing recalculations. Though there are technical solutions that take into account the expense of the recalc ( see [Make scheduled reputation recalcs to increase transparency](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35566/make-scheduled-reputation-recalcs-to-increase-transparency/38156#38156)   for one example) they have been declined.